# Check for character in web font

Tags: html, fonts, webfonts

How can I test if a particular web font contains a particular Unicode character? I can't simply include the character in some text, because a browser's font substitution mechanism may choose another font to display the character.

**EDIT**

This is the best solution I have been able to come up with so far:

First, you must download the *LastResort* font from Unicode: https://www.unicode.org/policies/lastresortfont_eula.html. (This is a bit tricky - I kept getting "network error", but in the end I succeeded.)

The *LastResort* font allegedly has a replacement icon for every Unicode character.

Now, let's assume that I want to check if the Google fonts "Pacifico" and "Merienda" contain the Unicode characters F and Ф (Unicode character 0424). I can use this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Font detect</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merienda">
    <style>
      @font-face {
        font-family: 'LastResort';
        src: url('LastResort.ttf') format('truetype');
      }

      p.pacifico {
          font-family: Pacifico, LastResort;
          font-size: 60pt;
      }

      p.lato {
          font-family: Merienda, LastResort;
          font-size: 60pt;
      }
    </style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <p class="pacifico">F &#x424;</p>
    <p class="lato">F &#x424;</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

This will display thus:

[image]

For Pacifico, both F and Ф are displayed, but for Merienda the Russian character Ф is replaced by a default icon from *LastResort*. So Pacifico contains Ф, Merienda does not.

Now, I don't know if this is a foolproof method, and I don't know if there is a simpler way to do it.

Comment: Depends: what's your usecase? Because the situation where "I don't want to load a huge font" is already solved by using WOFF2, which lets you load a single font, in small chunks at a time, depending on whether the already loaded chunks don't cover one or more characters on your page.

Comment: I need to display Unicode character C. I'm already loading font F, and I'm not sure if I need to load an additional font in order to display C. If I look at the browser on my computer, the character C is displayed, but that is no guarantee that another device will also display C if C is not part of F. So how do I determine if F contains C?

Comment: When do you want to determine this? I hope you don't want to perform this check on the user's computer; while it might be possible to make some guess about it, e.g by drawing it on a canvas and checking if the rendered characters produces the same bitmap as the default font, it is probably already too late isn't it? The best would be to read up about your font's specs, I guess they do provide the character sets they support from their download page, and otherwise, this [search query](https://www.google.com/search?q=woff+inspector) returned a few online services that are able to give it to you

Comment: No I don't want to check it on the user's computer. I'm perfectly happy with making a separate web page that I view only on my computer but which tells me if font F contains character C.

Comment: But I don't understand why this should be so hard. It's a perfectly straightforward question: Does this font contain this character? Surely, that should be simple to test. Font documentation is not always complete when specifying their character repertoire.

Comment: I've added a possible solution to my question, but I don't know if it's the best way to do things.

Comment: Your explanation is too abstract. I assume you don't _actually_ want "the character C", because the fonts you show definitely contain the capital letter C. It sounds like you're trying to make sure you have font(s) that will cover your content, in which case you want to do run your pages through a character analyser to see exactly which font (sub)sets you need. As for "I don't understand why this should be so hard": offline, on a computer, not hard at all. Almost trivial, even. In the browser? Super hard, because no browser comes with the font parser exposed via a JS API.

Comment: The real question is "why _not_ use another font"? Single character set fonts are much smaller than single page images, so your visitors are unlikely to notice the additional load, both in terms of time and in terms of bandwidth.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Wakamai Fondue](http://wakamaifondue.com/) is a tool that will tell you about which characters a font contains. It'll also tell you about any OpenType feature inside the font, and some more details. (Full disclosure: I wrote that tool)

If you want to check it at the client side, I think there's no way around trying to render the character and then check if it's actually been rendered. If you use [Adobe Blank](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/adobe-blank/) as a fallback font you could check if it rendered the character (width would be > 0) or not (width would be 0).

Comment: Thank you. I was not aware of the Adobe Blank font. Using it as a fallback font, and then using JavaScript to query the width of the interesting character works very nicely for me!

Comment: By the way, RoelN, Wakamai Fondue is a very nice tool!